# How to subtract Total from conditioned sum in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to do the following:

1) Find the total rows in a table
2) Find the total rows that meets a certain criteria.

3) Subtract (1) from (2).

Sample table Employees:

```
    EmployeeID  Nationality
    1           Brazil
    2           Korea
    3           Germany
    4           Brazil
    5           Brazil
```

What I've tried:

```
    SELECT count(EmployeeID) as Total from Employees
    UNION
    SELECT count(EmployeeID) as Brazilians from Employees
    WHERE Nationality = 'Brazil'
```

Result:

```
Total
5
3
```

Row 1 will give me the total Employees. Row 2 will give me the Brazilian Employees. 
I used UNION to see if I could subtract row 2 from row 1.

I could do this using CASE and SUM(), but that would require the row_number() function, which I can't use given that I'm using WebSQL. Is there another way to index these rows to be able to subtract?

Is there another approach I could use to solve this seemingly simple problem?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but base on your union , the first row would be the total number of rows, the 2nd is all brazillian employees , then you want to subtract, something like 5 - 3 base on your query?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, made a typo: Row1 = Total and Row2 = Brazilian Employees. Yes, my goal is to do 5-3 after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about counting the rows that don't meet that criteria?

```
SELECT COUNT(EmployeedID) as non_brazilians 
FROM Employees 
WHERE Nationality <> 'Brazil';
```

Comment: != comparison is deprecated, and I'm not sure if all dbms products support it. My tip is to use <> instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) as TotalRows,
       sum(case when Nationality = 'Brazil' then 1 else 0 end) as Brazilians,
       sum(case when Nationality <> 'Brazil' then 1 else 0 end) as nonBrazilians
from Employee;
```

This assumes that `Nationality` is never `NULL`.  If that is possible, the last condition should be:

```
       sum(case when Nationality = 'Brazil' then 0 else 1 end) as nonBrazilians
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT count(*) AS TotalRows 
        , (SELECT count(EmployeeID) FROM WHERE Nationality = 'Brazil') as Brazilians
        , (count(*) - (SELECT count(EmployeeID) FROM WHERE Nationality = 'Brazil')) AS Subtract1From2
 FROM Employee
```